# react natives status bar give errors

Tags: react-native, expo

t try this code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
     />
<Text> just test </Text> 
</view>
```

but then i run through expo its give a error

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a
>   measure function!

i dont know why how can i fix this error ?
note:i try in android phone using exop link like exp://dd.**:80

Comment: `</view>` should be `</View>`

Comment: And also indent your code white spaces causes issue in JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the status bar with some CO2 visualization content.

This is the source code: https://github.com/JyotibenSapariya/CO2-Visualization-

you can check it.

Its based on javascript so I hope you can use it.

thanks...

Comment: What is CO2 Visualization ?

Comment: CO2 visualization means in every 10 sec how much carbon has been emitted into the air. that's call CO2 visualization. Here I have taken the **random data** to visualize the carbon emission. The real app is in progress... thanks